# Matching up array data to sub-array data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a sub-array *itemdata* with a length of 6 rows. This data was originally in found in the main array but has been reformatted so there is 1 unique product per line.

I have the main array *saledata* with a length of 4 rows which looks a bit like this:

```
            id    sub-array
        0   001   [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '78', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}]
        1   002   [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '80', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}]
        2   003   [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '85', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}, {'type': 'line_items', 'id': '86', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}]
        3   004   [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '92', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}, {'type': 'line_items', 'id': '93', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}]
```

Then I have the sub-array *itemdata* (which is basically just json normalized column *sub-array*):

```
    type        id   attributes.status   attributes.quantity    attributes.various_other_data
0   line_item   78   allocated           1                      etc
0   line_item   80   allocated           2                      etc
0   line_item   85   allocated           1                      etc
1   line_item   86   allocated           1                      etc
0   line_item   92   allocated           2                      etc
1   line_item   93   allocated           2                      etc
```

At the moment, I'm treating sub-array as a string (after it's been json normalized for the second dataframe) which allows me to perform this:

```
for f in itemdata['id']:
    df['sub-array'].str.contains(f)
```

Which yields the following:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: relationships.line_items.data, dtype: bool
```

Which is all correct! But now I'm trying to match up the sub-array to the parent array, matching the index of the above results to the initial array *saledata* where True but struggling to find the right way to do this.

Python doesn't seem to like the below approach (truth value of a Series is ambiguous yada yada yada) and not sure how to proceed.

```
for f in itemdata['id']:
    if df['sub-array'].str.contains(f) == True:
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is what I'm looking for (note the etc's are off & unsure of pandas will allow multiple rows to have the same index value - not a huge issue if not):

```
         id   type         itemdata.id   itemdata.attributes.status   itemdata.attributes.quantity
    0   001   line_items   78            allocated              etc
    1   002   line_items   80            allocated              etc
    2   003   line_items   85            allocated              etc
    2   003   line_items   86            allocated              etc
    3   004   line_items   92            allocated              etc
    3   004   line_items   93            allocated              etc
```

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Comment: I should've added that into OP, I'll edit it in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) if need append `id` (or multiple columns) after normalize `sub-array` with set indices by exploded rows by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
import ast

df['sub-array'] = df['sub-array'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

s = df['sub-array'].explode()

cols = ['id']
df = df[cols].add_suffix('_parent').join(pd.json_normalize(s).set_index(s.index))
print (df)
  id_parent        type  id attributes.status  attributes.quantity  \
0       001  line_items  78         allocated                    1   
1       002  line_items  80         allocated                    2   
2       003  line_items  85         allocated                    1   
2       003  line_items  86         allocated                    1   
3       004  line_items  92         allocated                    2   
3       004  line_items  93         allocated                    2   

  attributes.various_other_data  
0                           etc  
1                           etc  
2                           etc  
2                           etc  
3                           etc  
3                           etc
```

If need processing only `id` column and `id` values are unique create helper Series and use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.set_index('id')['sub-array'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().str.get('id')
df['id_parent'] = df['id'].map(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the variety of answers! Only really need id_parent so reckon bottom answer is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

So you can generate the main array by:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
saledata = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['001', '002', '003', '004'],
    'sub-array': [[{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '78', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}],
                  [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '80', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}],
                  [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '85', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}},
                   {'type': 'line_items', 'id': '86', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 1, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}],
                  [{'type': 'line_items', 'id': '92', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}},
                   {'type': 'line_items', 'id': '93', 'attributes': {'status': 'allocated', 'quantity': 2, 'various_other_data': 'etc'}}]
                 ]
})

itemdata = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['line_item', 'line_item', 'line_item', 'line_item', 'line_item', 'line_item'],
    'id': ['78', '80', '85', '86', '92', '93'],
    'attributes.status': ['allocated', 'allocated', 'allocated', 'allocated', 'allocated', 'allocated'],
    'attributes.quantity': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'attributes.various_other_data': ['etc', 'etc', 'etc', 'etc', 'etc', 'etc']
})
```

```
In [4]: import numpy as np                                                                                                 

In [5]: item_id2sale_ids = {i_id: np.where(df['sub-array'].apply(lambda x: any(item['id'] == i_id for item in x))) for i_id
   ...:  in itemdata['id']}                                                                                                

In [6]: item_id2sale_ids                                                                                                   
Out[6]: 
{'78': (array([0], dtype=int32),),
 '80': (array([1], dtype=int32),),
 '85': (array([2], dtype=int32),),
 '86': (array([2], dtype=int32),),
 '92': (array([3], dtype=int32),),
 '93': (array([3], dtype=int32),)}
```